# PhalconPHP MSSQL Driver

Tags: php, sql-server, azure-sql-database, phalcon

Does anybody know if one can connect to a MSSQL Server database using phalconphp?

When I try to generate a modelI I get the following error :

> Phalcon DevTools (1.2.6)
>   Error: Adapter sqlsrv is not supported

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE :

Hi guys,

The author replied to my email asking for installation instructions, I have asked him to
update the README.md in the repository.

Herewith his response :

Sorry that i didn't explain anything~
you could put it anywhere, just remember to add the "namespace" to "folder path" config

1. copy "test/app/library/db" folder to your library folder
2. add the "namespace" to "folder path" setting
   //Register some namespaces
   $loader->registerNamespaces(

   ```
   array(
       "Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo"    => "library/db/adapter/",

       "Twm\Db\Dialect"    => "library/db/dialect/"

       )
   );
   ```

by the way, i found it only works under 1.2.0 ~ 1.2.4
i'm working on 2.0 using zephir

good luck

Kevin Yu

Comment: I stumbled upon this package : https://github.com/fishjerky/phalcon-mssql. Although I made all the modifications it seems that the phalconphp developer tools does not support this driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[github.com/fishjerky/phalcon-mssql](http://github.com/fishjerky/phalcon-mssql) is your answer. But
I had the same issue with this adapter.

So I changed from

```
    "{$descriptor['pdoType']}:host={$descriptor['host']};dbname={$descriptor['dbname']}"
```

to

```
    "{$descriptor['pdoType']}:server={$descriptor['host']};database={$descriptor['dbname']}"
```

Also you need to make sure 'sqlsrv' is set for $config->database->pdoType.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no out of the box connectivity of MSSQL with PhalconPHP but you can use various packages from Composer to provide this functionality.

Here is one package that I found the most promising :-

> https://github.com/dg/dibi

UPDATE :

> http://dibiphp.com/en/download

Check this link or install it via Composer, and check the documentation on the Github page or refer to this API Documentation

> http://api.dibiphp.com/2.1/

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look

Comment: Had a look, the website doesnt even work properly. 404 - on all the web pages.